# Google scholar citation counting suddenly drops, very recently

Tags: citations, google-scholar

Very recently, I had noticed that almost all scholars, from all countries and from all different universities, that I am aware of, their Google scholar citations counting suddenly drop (of the scale of 10, to 100 to 1000 to 10^4 counting, depending on your academic ranks and total citations).

One can check https://scholar.google.com/

Many people (almost all people) are affected.

Is there some policy changing?

Also it looks that the Google Scholar citation counts much less than ADSABS-Harvard system http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abstract_service.html, is there a reason behind it?

Comment: You'd have to ask Google about this- they apparently changed how they search for citations and decide what sources to include.  FWIW, I haven't noticed any such change in my Google profile.

Comment: Which email do you recommend me to send to Google Scholar? I never knew one can reach them. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't noticed this. Only Google can answer this, but perhaps if you look at lists of citing articles you will be able to notice which ones have been removed and then can guess why.

Comment: "I had noticed that almost all scholars, from all countries and from all different universities" -- how did you collect this evidence?

Comment: I looked at the Harvard link that you provided and see nothing. What do you want us to look at? Vote to close as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: It is true, I find the google citations suddenly drop again and again...

Comment: Please give links if it is possible, whom should I contact?